# Adobe Pro 11 - Expand Content With Checked Checkbox

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, adobe

I am attempting to create a service request form via Adobe Pro 11 (smart form) and am running into difficulty with allowing content to shift objects down the pages. Currently I have text boxes and labels hidden, which then become visible when a check box is checked. I don't want the hidden content to take up space on the page, unless it needs to be visible to the user.

How do I get content to expand and push already visible content down the page? For example, if I have three check boxes and the user clicks the first check box, I want the content to display above the remaining two check boxes (they need to shift down).

```
var desktopHide = event.target.isBoxChecked(0)?display.visible:display.hidden;
this.getField("quantityDesktopMoveTextBox").display = desktopHide;
this.getField("quantityDesktopMoveLabel").display = desktopHide;
```

Comment: Can you show what you are trying now?

Comment: Here is a small example: var desktopHide = event.target.isBoxChecked(0)?display.visible:display.hidden; 
this.getField("quantityDesktopMoveTextBox").display = desktopHide; 
this.getField("quantityDesktopMoveLabel").display = desktopHide; --- When the label and textbox become visible, Id like the objects below to shift down.

Answer (score 0):

For such a scenario, Adobe Propaganda would say you'd have to use a dynamic XFA form (created with LiveCycle Designer). This would indeed provide the easiest way, by using subforms (see documentation).

It is, however, possible to do it with AcroForms. However, it is a little bit messy, and does not work with every version of Reader. What you would do in this case, is putting the contents which should shift in fields as well. Then you set up a pagination routine which places/moves/creates those fields accordingly.

A client of mine has a whole set of such dynamic multilingual forms in regular use. For an in-depth discussion and quotes, feel free to contact me in private.